# CSS border-image gradient works in Chrome, not Firefox or IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

How do I get the following effect from Chrome to work in Firefox and IE?

**HTML**

```
<a class="button-style">Evil Whales</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button-style
{
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,
   rgba(129,232,117,1) 0%,
   rgba(129,232,117,1) 50%,
   rgba(62,179,48,1) 51%,
   rgba(62,179,48,1) 100%);

 border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
   rgba(155,156,157,1) 0%,
   rgba(246,249,252,1) 100%) 25 30 10 20 repeat;

 border-image-repeat: stretch;

 border-width: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the `border-style` to let it work in Firefox. I'm not sure about IE (I can't check it here unfortunately). See the updated code below and the outcome in Firefox is this:

[image]

```css
.button-style {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(129, 232, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(129, 232, 117, 1) 50%, rgba(62, 179, 48, 1) 51%, rgba(62, 179, 48, 1) 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(155, 156, 157, 1) 0%, rgba(246, 249, 252, 1) 100%) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
  border-style: solid; /*Added */
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  border-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a class="button-style">Evil Whales</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tricks has a great article on linear-gradients and there is also a section on browser support: https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Try using the vendor prefixes shown below:

```
.gradient {

  /* Fallback (could use .jpg/.png alternatively) */
  background-color: red;

  /* SVG fallback for IE 9 (could be data URI, or could use filter) */
  background-image: url(fallback-gradient.svg); 

  /* Safari 4, Chrome 1-9, iOS 3.2-4.3, Android 2.1-3.0 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(red), to(#f06d06));

  /* Safari 5.1, iOS 5.0-6.1, Chrome 10-25, Android 4.0-4.3 */
  background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

  /* Firefox 3.6 - 15 */
  background-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

  /* Opera 11.1 - 12 */
  background-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(left, red, #f06d06);

  /* Opera 15+, Chrome 25+, IE 10+, Firefox 16+, Safari 6.1+, iOS 7+, Android 4.4+ */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, red, #f06d06);

}
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image) the border-image property must be accompanied by the border style property, "Note that both the border-style and border-width must be specified (not set to none or 0) for border-images to work according to spec, though older implementations may not have this requirement. Partial support refers to supporting the shorthand syntax, but not the individual properties (border-image-source, border-image-slice, etc)."